# wifi security with traffic monitoring program

Tags: security, networking

Here is a question about my wifi or network security.
I saw that someone receive my traffic from my browser because information about my work detected in social network like Facebook.
I installed some traffic monitoring program for my wifi - there are source, destination, protocol, length and info in this program.
How can I see who received my traffic with this program?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer; You almost certainly cannot.

Long answer: Most network monitoring at the enterprise level is preformed via tools on the routers, switches, and firewalls that make up the network. These tools typically don't modify traffic, and don't need to send any information over the network, so there's really no way to tell which link in the network is actually doing the monitoring. The only way to tell that monitoring is happening at all, aside from subtle timing delays that are very noise prone, is by trying to access a blocked site, reading corporate policies, or getting a call from HR.

If your traffic is being monitored by someone else on the network, i.e. another network client instead of the infrastructure, then you still can't tell who or what or even if you are being monitored. Wifi sends traffic as radio, and wifi sniffing just listens in to those radio signals; in most cases, its entirely passive, and thus undetectable.